# How to delete a row in a database with pdo ($stmt stated false)

Tags: php, database, pdo, sql-delete

I'm coding a blog to get experience with php.

I want the admin to be able to delete a post, but when I click the `delete-button` which should actually bring me to a function that deletes the post I get the error `Call to a member function execute() on boolean`.

Here is the code of the `postsRepository.php` which interacts with the database and the function in the `postsAdminController.php`:

```
public function deletePost($id)
{
  $table = $this->getTableName();
  $model = $this->getModelName();

  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE * FROM `{$table}` WHERE id = :id");

  $stmt->execute([
   'id' => $id
  ]);
 }


public function deletePost()
{
  $id = $_GET['id'];

  if ($this->postsRepository->deletePost($id)) {
    header("Location: posts-admin");
    return;
  } else {

  }
}
```

I've var_dumped the $id right before the $stmt, it's correct and the shown error says the it is because of `$stmt->execute([`.

**The $stmt is stated as false when I var_dumped it, but why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for `DELETE` is

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE ...
```

Remove the `*` in your query.

`$stmt` is false because *"If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling)."*

For more informations, check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: well, seems like I'm just stupid, thank you very much :D

Comment: You aren't stupid.